# andengine for c sharp

Tags: c#, java, android

I've come across some discussion about C# and Java and it seems that a lot of programmers here in StackOverflow like C# more than java. [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575513/why-is-c-sharp-suddenly-so-popular)

I'm just curious if I can use the andegine library in C# using mono?
OR to be precise can I use java libraries in C# when creating an android application?

Is there a disadvantage of using C# instead of Java and if it is possible to use a Java library in C#, can you give me some example? I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use a Java library you should use Java.

It isn't possible to directly use a Java library from C#, but if you want to use C# you could:

- Find a similar library that is written for .NET.
- Andengine is open source. You could choose to port it to C#, though this would take a long time.

Comment: @Tifa: It means rewriting it in C#.

Comment: Thats a lot of work :) hmmm Do you know software to convert csharp code to java? maybe if theres no choice ill have to convert it.. T_T

Comment: @Tifa: I don't. But I imagine that you aren't the first to ask that question. Try searching the site for other people who have asked the same question.